# Can not to authorize with Named Credentials '23 using API-key

Tags: salesforce, authorization, apex, api-key, callouts

I Created code, that do request from Google Maps to get geolocation. I have triggered flow, where I use Apex code to send my request.
I need to hide my endpoint and Api-Key using Named Credentials.

It seems that it sending request with this part:
 `String geocodingUrl = 'callout:Geo1' + '/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + encodedAddress;`
But in logs I see that Request Denied, as I understand it mean that authorization was fall. For this part I have this code:

```
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
            httpRequest.setEndpoint(request.geocodingUrl);
            httpRequest.setMethod('GET');
            httpRequest.setHeader('Authorization', 'Client-ID ' + '{!$Credential.Geo2.Key}');
            HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(httpRequest);
```

Can somebody help me please?